# Reply script not storing name in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script to reply to a user that sent a message, and it is not storing any name in the database when i use the reply script.

Here's the viewing script that sets the session for the reply.

```
 $query = "SELECT `to`, `from`, rank, gender, picture, title, msg FROM kaoscraft_pm WHERE `to` = '$username1' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $gender = $row['gender'];


  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];
        $username2 = $_SESSION['reply'];
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  echo '<div class="vpside">';
    if(!empty($row['picture'])) {
    echo '<img class="pictest" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . 'nopic.png' . '" />';
    }
  if(!empty($row['from'])) {
      echo '<p>From:<br />' . $row['from'] . '</p>';
      echo '<a href="reply.php">Reply</a>';
    }
```

And then the script for the reply:

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username2 = $_SESSION['reply'];
    // Grab the profile data from the POST
     $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags( trim($_POST['msg'])));
     $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['title']));
     $to = $username2;

    // Update the post data in the database
      if (!empty($msg) && !empty($title)) {
        // Only set the picture column if there is a new picture
    $query = "INSERT INTO kaoscraft_pm (`from`, `to`, `rank`, `gender`, `picture`, `msg_date`, `title`, `msg`) VALUES ('$username', '$to', '$rank', '$gender', '$picture', NOW(), '$title', '$msg')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: I see that you're populating $_SESSION['reply'] from the queries resultset, have you checked to confirm that you DB has the proper data?

Comment: OK, have you checked if the value is actually there in session? Maybe log the value using error_log and see if the session has the proper value?

Comment: There is not a value, this is the problem

Comment: OK. First please ensure that the value is successfully set initially in `$_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];`. If it is then the session is not storing the value properly, have you started the session properly, ensure that the value is not cleared or the session is not destroyed during the chain of events.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `$username2` but then you use `$username` in your query.

Comment: yes, but `$to` is the thing that is not being put in, and I have `$to = $username2`

Comment: What if it's a mysql error. Try this: `die(mysql_error());` after your mysql queries. Try it on both and see if it gives back an error

Answer (score 0):

As @albxn says,

`'from'` will not be populated as you have `$username` in the sqlquery

but also, you're trying to populate `'to'` from `$_SESSION['reply'];`

and you didn't do  a `session_start()`

Comment: This is a snippet of code, you're not going to see `session_start` because it is not in this part of code you see. `From` is populated perfectly, `to` is what I am having the problem with